# Построение моделей вложенности Django

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Допустим, есть таблица авто

```
ИД Наименование
1  Мазда MX-5
2  ЛАДА Гранта
3  Киа спектра
4  Нива Шевроле 4х4
```

Ну и примерно такая таблица каталога

```
ИД Название                  Уровень_вложенности Родитель_ИД
1  Отечественные автомобили  1                   null
2  Иномарки                  1                   null
3  Мазда                     2                   2
4  ЛАДА                      2                   1
5  Киа                       2                   2
6  Нива                      2                   1
7  Передний привод           3                   3
8  Передний привод           3                   4
9  Передний привод           3                   5    
10 Задний привод             3                   3
11 Задний привод             3                   4
12 Задний привод             3                   5    
13 Полный привод             3                   3
14 Полный привод             3                   5
15 Полный привод             3                   6

Нужно получать: 
Иномарки > = Мазда MX-5, Киа спектра
Иномарки > Мазда > Задний привод  = Мазда MX-5
Отечественные автомобили > Нива > Полный привод  = Нива Шевроле 4х4
и тд.
```

Каким образом моделями джанго можно эффективно организовать  хранение многоуровневых зависимостей?
Создать ещё одну таблицу где будет примерно такое?

```
(допустим для мазды)
ИД_авто ИД_каталог_итем
1       2
1       3
1       10
```

Answer (score -1):

Не совсем понимаю смысл второй таблицы и зачем так усложнять? Делается 1 общая таблица со всеми автомобилями и их характеристиками. Если нужно получить какой-то определённый автомобиль из БД по определённым характеристикам, то у моделей Django есть метод filter. Если нужно получить какие-то уникальные значения (например марки авто), то есть метод distinct

Comment: в рамках одной таблицы не практично, у одного авто может быть много категорий каталога, плюс будут проблемы с перестроением иерархии, если мы захотим добавить ещё одну категорию или подкатегорию. Так же, будет большой объём данных в авто, которые будут постоянно записываться, удалятся, не желательно использовать много ключей в этой таблице.

Comment: @АндрейИванов как раз в одной таблице более практично и это легче реализовать, всё остальное очень абстрактно и я не могу ничего посоветовать и никто не сможет, нужна конкретика

Comment: Не очень понимаю, как это сделать в одной таблице при неоднородности, что если у нас будет таблица не авто, а транспортные средства. И помимо машин там будет "самокат" этот элемент не применим к категориям каталога авто, и будет иметь свою иерархию:  к примеру: "Самокат > городской  > Материал колес: полиуретан > Конструкция: складной > = Ridex Rapid 2.0

Comment: @АндрейИванов вот для самокатов отдельная таблица

Comment: С машинами был не удачный пример. На самом деле у меня таблица продукты, почти все элементы неоднородны, там могут быть от крепления для телефона, до шаровых опор.

Comment: @АндрейИванов в Django появилось поле JSONField, можно в это поле любые словари и массивы вставлять и так описывать продукт

Comment: @Inventor https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Нормальная_форма

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov впервые о таком слышу, но после фразы "Нормализация не имеет целью увеличение производительности работы" перестал читать этот, по моему мнению, бред. Я молчу про то что эту статью писал тот, кто нормально не владеет русским языком.

Comment: Да, Edgar "Ted" Codd, изобретатель реляционная модели данных (основа SQL), знал русский гораздо хуже вас. Речь о том, что системы дольжны не только не тормозить, но и не глючить. И вторая задача гораздо сложней.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov я про автора статьи на википедии. Её точно писал не он